# iOS convert IP Address to integer and backwards

Tags: ios, string

Say I have a NSString
NSString *myIpAddress = @"192.168.1.1"

I want to convert this to a integer - increment it an then convert it back to NSString.

Does iOS have an easy way to do this other than using bit mask and shifting and sprintf?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this is what I do in [my app](http://clkuk.tradedoubler.com/click?p=23708&a=1613651&url=http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/subnet-calc-pro/id303555213?mt=8&uo=4&partnerId=2003):

```
NSArray *ipExplode = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
int seg1 = [ipExplode[0] intValue];
int seg2 = [ipExplode[1] intValue];
int seg3 = [ipExplode[2] intValue];
int seg4 = [ipExplode[3] intValue];

uint32_t newIP = 0;
newIP |= (uint32_t)((seg1 & 0xFF) << 24);
newIP |= (uint32_t)((seg2 & 0xFF) << 16);
newIP |= (uint32_t)((seg3 & 0xFF) << 8);
newIP |= (uint32_t)((seg4 & 0xFF) << 0);

newIP++;
NSString *newIPStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u.%u.%u.%u", 
        ((newIP >> 24) & 0xFF), 
        ((newIP >> 16) & 0xFF), 
        ((newIP >> 8) & 0xFF), 
        ((newIP >> 0) & 0xFF)];
```

Comment: I think you will need

    int seg1 = [[ipExplode objectAtIndex:0] intValue];

Comment: Not true. This is using literal syntax.